# Python 3 log in to website and download file

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, urllib

Hope someone can help... so here it goes.

I've searched in this forum and used a lot of resources but I'm stuck logging on the houzz.com website.
Basically I want to log in and then retrieve the csv file which contains all the orders.
I've used the same code with Amazon and it worked but in this case is not working here and I receive the following error (error 500):
[Error log in houzz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDNsE.png)

This is the code I'm currently using (some bits are in comment to debug, also I've set up all the data fields analysing the actual POST request to be sure name of the fields and value were correct, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCAkM.png) )

```
import bs4, requests, urllib.request`

session = requests.Session()`

session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36'}

# Log in to houzz
print('Logging in...')
response = session.get('https://www.houzz.com/signin/')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

signin_data = {}
# signin_form = soup.find('form', {'id': 'signinForm'})

# for field in signin_form.find_all('input'):
#     try:
#         signin_data[field['id']] = field['value']
#     except:
#         signin_data[field['id']] = ''

# print(signin_data)
signin_data[u'op'] = 'l'
signin_data[u'un'] = 'myusername'
signin_data[u'pwd'] = 'mypassword'
signin_data[u'rdr'] = 'https://www.houzz.com/'
signin_data[u'k'] = 'y'
signin_data[u'jt'] = 'AwA3yxJb1ahdYi5vieLiK-bK7DeXzEu_Eq8erpWgcOvcrYbzT0g'
signin_data[u'ajaxRequestId'] ='1'
signin_data[u'pageRequestId'] = '194e405c-77db-4de8-b21c-1d960e4af475'
signin_data[u'isResiv'] = 'false'
signin_data[u'__ct'] = 'AwA3yxJb1ahdYi5vieLiK-bK7DeXzEu_Eq8erpWgcOvcrYbzT0g'
signin_data[u'_csrf'] = 'AwA3yxJb1ahdYi5vieLiK-bK7DeXzEu_Eq8erpWgcOvcrYbzT0g'

# print(signin_data)

response = session.post('https://www.houzz.com/authorize', data = signin_data)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

# warning = soup.find('div', {'id': 'signinErrors'})

# if warning.text!='':
#     print('Failed to login: {0}'.format(warning.text))
# else :
#     print('Log in Successful')

response = session.get('https://www.houzz.com/browseBuyerOrders/vname=capolavori')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(soup)

urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://www.houzz.com/downloadOrdersCsv/vName=capolavori/s=all/sib=1', 'houzz_report.csv')

session.close()
```

Many thanks!